# Python - More efficient way of formatting output from reading a file

Tags: python

I have a text file containing the following:
(Taking the headings to be: Student ID, Name, Age, Favourite Subject)

```
1234,Luke,15,History,
1256,Hannah,17,Maths,
1278,Katherine,14,Geography,
1290,Rachael,12,French,
3412,James,16,Computer Science,
```

What I want to do is output the contents of this file to the user, to look like this:

```
Student ID    Name          Age    Favourite Subject
1234          Luke          15     History
1256          Hannah        17     Maths
1278          Katherine     14     Geography
1290          Rachael       12     French
3412          James         16     Computer Science
```

My current code, shown below, works just fine (it seems to me, at least), but I'm guessing there's a much better way to do it that would be more efficient? It feels like I might have made it more awkward than is necessary, with the appending to lists etc.

```
def formatOutput():
    headings = ["Student ID", "Name", "Age", "Favourite Subject"]
    formatID = []
    formatName = []
    formatAge = []
    formatFavSub = []


    with open("Students.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            info = line.split(",")
            formatID.append(info[0])
            formatName.append(info[1])
            formatAge.append(info[2])
            formatFavSub.append(info[3])

            formatOutput = [headings] + list(zip(formatID, formatName, formatAge, formatFavSub))


for i in formatOutput:
    print("{:<10}\t{:<9}\t{:<3}\t{:<17}".format(*i)) 

formatOutput()
```

Help's appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping it simple:

```
template = "{:<10}\t{:<9}\t{:<3}\t{:<17}"
print(template.format("Student ID", "Name", "Age", "Favourite Subject"))
with open('Students.txt') as studentsfile:
    for line in studentsfile:
        print(template.format(*line.split(',')))
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, especially the split with the splat.  However, adding another 20 columns would be painful with the format statement.

Comment: Adding dozens more columns would be a hassle indeed. But how many more could you realistically add on an 80- or 132-column terminal? And in that case I would suggest a list of column widths and  `r'{:<'+r'}\t{:<'.join(str(c) for c in colwidths)+r'}'`.

Comment: I have worked on some data projects that went from 160 columns to 210 columns, so it can be a reality.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Python csv module reader / writer, or the DictReader / DictWriter.

From the Python [csv document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Since I have time now, I've added a full solution on how I would personally with this code:

```
import csv

def format_row(data=None, widths=None):
    return '\t'.join([column.ljust(width, ' ')
                    for column, width in zip(data, widths)])

heading = ("Student Id", "Name", "Age", "Favorite Subject")
widths = (10, 9, 3, 17)
output = []

output.append(format_row(heading, widths))

with open('Students.txt', 'r') as f:
    csv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv:
        output.append(format_row(row, widths))

for line in output:
    print(line)
```

The format_row() method uses list comprehension to format the columns with the correct spacing.  The zip combines the column with its width.  This allows you to format each column accordingly.  Also note, in most cases, you would not want to space delimit the file AND add tab delimiters as well.  However, I added them since that is how you initially asked the question.  Finally, you want to add a check to make sure that you have enough rows and widths.  If not, you'll end up with an error.

Comment: You're reading a format different from the OP's input format, and producing a different output format too. While not useless, it's not really a great illustration of how you'd do it (aligned data output is more difficult than simple delimited output). Perhaps show how this can simplify their code by showing how `csv.reader` can replace multiple lines of their parsing code with more correct and simpler code.